# QGIS shortcuts saved in other GUI language

Tags: qgis, gui, shortcuts

My aim is to import .xml file with shortcuts saved in other QGIS user profile, in different GUI language. What could be a solution to avoid manual rewriting shortcuts?
QGIS 3.22+

Comment: Did you try Menu `Settings` > `User Profiles` > `Open Active Profile Folder` and look there where the shortcuts are saved?

Comment: Yes, cannot find them using words 'shortcut', 'shortcut'.  Have you got any idea where are they saved over there?

Answer (score 1):

Open Menu <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Keyboard Shortcuts...</kbd> and go to <kbd>Save...</kbd>. In the other profile, load the saved file the same way:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I understand the whole idea of import/export shortcuts. Please, try to open exported shortcuts.xml from English version of your profile and then import them in new profile which will be in Spanish (Settings - Optrions - General - language, it requires QGIS restart). Names for the shortcuts will be written in English, not Spanish, and that's a problem.